# It all starts with a message

Tags: cipher

I saw this in one of the forums I frequent (user said it was from reddit).

[image]

I tried to solve it, and the only thing I got was that there is one English letter followed by one hexadecimal number (this might not be correct). So help me find the answer to this code.

Comment: https://twitter.com/chronosproj

Comment: https://plus.google.com/+brianrose/posts/YB3o4igm6bp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found this answer somewhere in the comments on some other site:**

The message says "maybe its (it's) time to wake up".

It uses a simple caesar shift:
a1-a6 = A-F,
b1-b6 = G-L,
c1-c6 = M-R,
d1-d6 = S-X,
e1-e6 = Y-D (alphabet wraps around),
f1-f6 = E-J,
g1-g6 = K-P,
h1-h6 = Q-V, etc.

Capital letters are equal to a '0' of that letter group which correspond to the last number of the previous letter group:

E = e0 = d6 = X
F = f0 = e6 = D

Then each word has a different "shift-number" (how many letters the letters get "shifted" over):
With a "shift-number" of +4:

a1-a6 = W-B,
b1-b6 = C-H,
c1-c6 = I-N,
d1-d6 = O-T,
e1-e6 = U-Z,
f1-f6 = A-F, etc.

E = e0 = d6 = T
F = f0 = e6 = Z

Just use this principle, changing the "shift-numbers" for each word, to decrypt it. The first word has a "shift-number" of '+0', then '+4', then '+4', then '+14', then '+6', then '+14'.